# UITableView Not Scrolling

Tags: ios, scroll, touch, tableview

I have a tableview which will not budge when touched. It is very confusing to me. It is the most recently added subview (I checked - it is the last entry in my view's subviews array) and for some reason it just won't scroll up or down. If I tap multiple fingers wildly on the tableview it will one in a while highlight the cell under one of my fingers, but it will not scroll even a little. I have set the number of rows to 100 (many more than are visible on screen) and I have set the 'bounces', 'scrollEnabled', and 'userInteractionEnabled' properties to YES.

I know that I have not provided much to go on here, but if anyone could at least give some tips on how to go about debugging this I would be very grateful. Can I log from within the tableView gestureRecognizer handling method? Can I test where my touches are going?

Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some of your code

Comment: I think it is worth noting that in a simulator, scrolling works when you drag instead of two finger scrolling that you do usually on macbook.

Answer (score 3):

A TableView is basically a specialized ScrollView.  If it's not scrolling, it seems to me it could be one of two things.  Either something is on top of the TableView and is capturing the gesture events before the TableView can get them, or You have set the bounds and contentSize incorrectly.  For a TableView or ScrollView, the bounds of the view should be the visible area, and the contentSize (should be handled by the TableView without you needing to do anything) is the size of all the cells in the Table.

So I would check the bounds of the table view and make sure you are setting that to the contentSize, since that would cause it nor to scroll.

Just to make sure it's on the top, try calling

```
[view bringSubviewToFront:tableView];
```

Comment: It is to note that, the scrolling on tableview will actually work if you drag the   tableview in the simulator instead of trying to scroll using your two fingers on trackpad (_which is default on mac_).

Answer (score 2):

In my case tableview "User Interaction" was disabled. I just enabled it & works.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, tableView "canCancelContentTouches" was not enabled. I set it to true in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the frame of the parent on which the tableview is added? Make sure the parent view have correct frame to include the table view. I have faced this issue sometime back my table view was not responding to touches and there was some problem with frame size. Also do check the bounds and frames of your tableview

-anoop

Answer (score 1):

Please check tableview scroll is enabled.
I just hate XIB and Storyboard. After 30 mins of debugging it come to know that scroll was not enable in XIB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Table view is just a kind of scrollview. So in case it is not scrolling You should be sure that if the frame size of your table view is less than the contentSize of your table view. For this just log the frame and content size of tableView's scroll view. If you found that frame size is greater or equal to your content size, just correct your layout constrain of your view. And  I hope it will work.